# Limit of consecutive sum of binomials

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

Let $a$ be a positive integer. What is the limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\dbinom{an}{0}+\dbinom{an}{1}+\cdots+\dbinom{an}{n-1}}{2^{an}}$$ where $n$ takes on integer values?

Since the binomials can be approximated by a normal distribution when $n$ gets large, the answer should have something to do with the normal distribution probability distribution. But I'm confused what the relation is and how to derive the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability you're interested in is $\Pr[\mathrm{Bin}(an,1/2)<n]$. There are three cases: if $a<2$ then the limit is $0$, if $a = 2$ then it is $1/2$, if $a > 2$ then it is $1$. When $a \neq 2$, you can show this using Chebyshev's theorem. The case $a = 2$ can be handled directly, since by symmetry we know that
$$
\frac{\binom{2n}{0} + \cdots + \binom{2n}{n-1} + \frac{1}{2} \binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}} = \frac{1}{2},
$$
while $\binom{2n}{n}/2^n = O(1/\sqrt{n})$.